# Can't access to id attribute with document.activeElement

Tags: javascript, xul

I am developping a xul application using javascript.
In my code, I'm trying to find the xul element which has the focus when I click on an other element by doing :

```
var txtarea = document.activeElement;
```

In my case, the element which has the focus is a textbox.
The problem is I can access the value attribute of the textbox but I can't access the id attribute... Indeed, `txtarea.id` returns an empty string. So I can't check the txtarea element.

However, all textboxes have their own id.
Do you know why `txtarea.id` returns an empty string ?

Comment: are you sure your textArea has an id attribute.

Comment: Here is the code of the xul element : "<textbox disabled="true" id="commandAction"/>" So yes I'm sure.

Comment: textbox is not a valid HTML tag. I wouldn't be surprised if this was why you couldn't access id. Do you mean to use textarea?

Comment: I am not aware of `xul` but as for as HTML is concern I don't know a tag called `textbox`.

Comment: In HTML, there is not a textbox tag. It's specific to xul. It could be the reason. But I don't understand why I could access the value attribute.

Comment: `textbox`??? also check if that id is duplicate. im guessing its duplicate and you are getting the value of the first element with that id value